# Will any prop apart from the value prop work inside Context.Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-context

In this snippet below (taken from the [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-context)):

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react'
import 'jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { NameContext, NameProvider, NameConsumer } from '../react-context'

afterEach(cleanup)

/**
 * Test default values by rendering a context consumer without a
 * matching provider
 */
test('NameConsumer shows default value', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<NameConsumer />)
  expect(getByText(/^My Name Is:/)).toHaveTextContent('My Name Is: Unknown')
})

/**
 * To test a component tree that uses a context consumer but not the provider,
 * wrap the tree with a matching provider
 */
test('NameConsumer shows value from provider', () => {
  const tree = (
    <NameContext.Provider value="C3P0">
      <NameConsumer />
    </NameContext.Provider>
  )
  const { getByText } = render(tree)
  expect(getByText(/^My Name Is:/)).toHaveTextContent('My Name Is: C3P0')
})

/**
 * To test a component that provides a context value, render a matching
 * consumer as the child
 */
test('NameProvider composes full name from first, last', () => {
  const tree = (
    <NameProvider first="Boba" last="Fett">
      <NameContext.Consumer>
        {value => <span>Received: {value}</span>}
      </NameContext.Consumer>
    </NameProvider>
  )
  const { getByText } = render(tree)
  expect(getByText(/^Received:/).textContent).toBe('Received: Boba Fett')
})

/**
 * A tree containing both a providers and consumer can be rendered normally
 */
test('NameProvider/Consumer shows name of character', () => {
  const tree = (
    <NameProvider first="Leia" last="Organa">
      <NameConsumer />
    </NameProvider>
  )
  const { getByText } = render(tree)
  expect(getByText(/^My Name Is:/).textContent).toBe('My Name Is: Leia Organa')
})
```

I don't get the part where we are passing `first` and `last` as props to `NameProvider`.

**Assuming** the definition of these three is the following:

```
NameContext = createContext()
NameProvider = NameContext.Provider
NameConsumer = NameContext.Consumer
```

Are we allowed to pass props other than the `value` prop, inside the `Provider`.

If yes, can you please share an example of how it can be done. I can't seem to find it in the react docs as well.

Thanks in advance !! :D

Answer (score 4):

It's not very clear from those docs but there's a slight difference between `NameContext.Provider` and `NameProvider`. `NameContext.Provider` is the raw Provider returned from `React.createContext`, and only takes `value` as a prop.

In the `testing-library` docs, they don't explain it, but they have created a separate `NameProvider`, which wraps `NameContext.Provider`, and provides a `first/last` prop interface, something like this:

```
const NameProvider = ({ first, last, children }) => (
  <NameContext.Provider value={{ first, last }}>
    {children}
  </NameContext.Provider>
)
```

This allows you to create a Provider with a limited interface, which is useful if (for example) you're writing a library that other developers will be using, and you don't want to allow them full access to the Provider's `value` prop.